# How does the panel argument work in R?

Tags: r, graph

This the code I see in my book:

```
print(xyplot(lower + upper ~ x, data=NPL.bands(dataset$variable),
    panel = function(x,y,...) {
         panel.xyplot(x,y,...)
         panel.curve(pnorm(x,7.22,1.14), lwd=1.5)
     }))
```

So I start to read this as the following:
Plot both the upper and lower ends of the confidence band for this data set.

But after that I am confused. I know that the panel function can make more specialized changes to whatever is in the panel.

It seems that the code says "We're putting an xy function in this panel, and is going to be called through the xyplot function, and it will be a curve with the following arguments".

Am I right in assuming that once you call a panel argument, you can do panel.X where 'X' is any function that is relevant to what the panel argument initially called? (in this case, the function "function(x,y,...)")

Bonus question: How does R know what to pack into a "..." argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you were basically correct. The panel parameter in this instance is a function specified to accept two named arguments, `x` and `y` , and to possibly accept any further named arguments in the dots-list (but only if their names exactly match those of the particular panel functions. You can look up what named parameters might get assigned values by going to the help pages for `panel.xyplot` and `panel.curve`.

In this instance also you have two names on the LHS of the tilde in the formula, so each instance of `y` in the `panel.xyplot` functions will get passed vectors twice, once with `y` as `lower` and once as `upper`. The `panel.curve` call does not get these extra values because there is no `y` in its parameter list.

I'm assuming this NPL.band function is from package SMIR and that your data argument looks something like:

```
str( NPL.bands(y) )
#
List of 3
 $ x    : num [1:44] 0 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 ...
 $ lower: num [1:44] 0.000362 0.004418 0.011527 0.030885 0.054412 ...
 $ upper: num [1:44] 0.0996 0.1327 0.1627 0.2176 0.2683 ...
```

Looking at ?panel.xyplot we see:

```
panel.xyplot(x, y, type = "p",
             groups = NULL,
             pch, col, col.line, col.symbol,
             font, fontfamily, fontface,
             lty, cex, fill, lwd,
             horizontal = FALSE, ...,
             grid = FALSE, abline = NULL,
             jitter.x = FALSE, jitter.y = FALSE,
             factor = 0.5, amount = NULL,
             identifier = "xyplot")
```

So you could add any of those parameters, either named or positionally matched for "type" through "horizontal" but only as named for the later ones after the "...", and they would be matched inside the `panel.xyplot` function call. Try adding `col=c("darkred", "orange"),` right after the data argument comma.

Also take the time to review the `?Lattice` page.

Comment: Thank you very much - this was very helpful.